# Grails rendering same class differently depending on property location

Tags: json, grails

In my grails application I want to render hierarchy of objects as JSON response. There are several properties of java.util.Date type, specified on different levels, having different names. Depending on the location and name, I want to render date differently, something like this:

```
{
...
    "touristBirthday": "1980-10-11",
    "flight": {
        ...
        "flightTime": "2013-10-11 10:00",
        ...
    }
...
}
```

Note that `touristBirthday` and `flightTime` have both java.util.Date type, but should be rendered differently. So grails object marshaller is not really useful for me.
In some parts of the application I've already done conversion manually by transforming my model beans into maps and then overriding entries in these maps, but doing this in each case produces lots of unmaintainable mess, especially when the hierarchy has many levels.

Is there any plugin or simple solution to this problem? So I can simply specify name/location of my property and the way to render it, overriding default object marshaller.

P.S. changing the model (property types) is not really an option for me, as the model comes from another application.

Comment: But why grails object marshaller is not useful for you?

Comment: Because if I use it `JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Date)` then my dates will be rendered the same way everywhere, and i want to render them differently depending on the property name/location

Comment: why not to register it for base class? flight, etc? and just create appropriate string representation for a field

Comment: @IgorArtamonov that's one of the solutions, but the model is huge, so I don't want to duplicate it in object marshaller definition